# Getting error while trying to sudo bash file.sh

Tags: networking, 15.04

I have just recently switched from windows to Linux and i am unable to connect to the Ethernet. My university requires authentication software in order to connect to the Ethernet. They provide the download links on their website for the Linux version of the software. If you would like to take a look at the software here's the address 
http://www2.zzu.edu.cn/service/sys/RG_SU_For_Linux_1_30_setup.zip

After I downloaded the file and extracted I used `sudo bash rjsupplicant.sh` as well as the `chmod +x` command suggested in the Zip's readme. Both commands returned the error

```
Sysctl: write error: Bad file descriptor
Sysctl: write error: Bad file descriptor
Sysctl: write error: Bad file descriptor

Please select dhcp mode, using "--help" command to detail.
```

When I applied for an Ethernet connection at the university office I was given an ip address, gateway, subnet mask, and DNS server. I also needed to spoof my Mac address in order for the software to properly authenticate me. I have already changed all the settings for my wired connection via system settings>network>wired>options under the Ethernet tab and ipv4 settings to the values provided by the university network office

I have attempted to look up solutions, however, I do not have the expertise to follow them through :(. I would appreciate a step by step solution. I also apologize in advance if it is against the forum rules to post links.

Answer (score 0):

Well the chmod is a system command and not a comlmand related to your scrip so it should work anyway should work anyway. What yoo have to do actually is :

1. Go to the directory where you have downloaded your zip file:

   ```
   cd /<the directory path>/
   ```
2. Unzip the file

   ```
   unzip RG_SU_For_Linux_1_30_setup.zip
   ```
3. Go to the created directory

   ```
   cd rjsupplicant
   ```
4. Add execution right to the file.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x rjsupplicant.sh
   ```
5. Now you have to run your scrip

   `/rjsupplicant.sh -a 1` for the wired connection.

   `./rjsupplicant.sh -a 0` for the wifi

You can get more options if you type:

```
./rjsupplicant.sh --help
```

Comment: could you tag the problem as solved Thank you .

Comment: Thank you, using ./rjsupplicant.sh -- help I found the command to change it to dhcp mode: ./rjsupplicant.sh -d 1. However the program still does not let me authenticate and connect to Ethernet. The program had shown in the terminal that all my ip, subnet mask, DNS, gateway, and Mac address settings had changed. My system settings>network no longer shows my wired or wireless network so I am unable to change it from there.